# Use Binary Data Instead of File in Python Numpy

Tags: python, file, numpy, file-io, binary

I need to read a file into a numpy array. The program only has access to the binary data from the file, and the original file extension if needed. The data the program receives would look something like the "data" shown below.

```
data = open('file.csv', 'rb').read()
```

I need to generate an array from this binary data. I do not have permission to write the data to a file so doing that then sending the file to numpy won't work.

Is there some way I can treat the binary data like a file so I can use the numpy function below?

```
my_data = genfromtxt(data, delimiter=',')
```

Thanks.

Comment: I know the library 'pandas' has a `read_csv(file, delimiter)` function, see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @LukasR Thank you. I did not know pandas could receive buffer objects.

Comment: `genfromtxt` works with anything that feeds it lines.  It can use a list of lines.  It can use a file that's already open.  From its docs: `fname : file, str, pathlib.Path, list of str, generator
    File, filename, list, or generator to read. `

Comment: If the`csv` is really a comma separated file, `data` isn't `binary data`, even though you read it with `rb` mode.  Look at it.  It probably is one big string.  You can split it into a list of lines with `data.splitlines()`.